# Power BI File Not Uploading

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to upload a report to Power Bi Service.
The report was created in Power BI Desktop.

The file is 4MB in size. In the past, this file took 5 seconds to upload.

Any ideas why it might be taking longer now?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved after I restarted my machine.

Problem solved.